# Concrete example of a set with a lower degree of unsolvability

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions, halting-problem, turing-completeness

Post's problem, posed in 1944 by Post, was to know if there is a recursively enumerable set, which, being undecidable, was not equivalent to the Halting problem under Turing reducibility. While I've seen the proof that such sets exist (the book [Gems of Theoretical Computer Science](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-60322-8) has a chapter on this), the proof works by (a bit artificially) constructing Turing incomparable sets. So far, I haven't seen an example of a concrete "natural" example of an undecidable set below the Halting problem, which I would like to find.

[Here](https://math.colorado.edu/%7Emayr/teaching/math6010spring21/class27.pdf) are some notes on Post's problem, with a proof idea of its solution.

My first attempt at coming up with such a set would be to consider somethin like A = {BB(n) : n $\in$ Halt}, because, even if I am supplied with A as an oracle, I can't seem to use it to know if n is in Halt without computing BB(n), which is an uncomputable function (the busy beaver function), but I'm a bit stuck trying to just prove that it is undecidable.

So my question is: do you know examples of concrete undecidable sets, with a lower degree of unsolvability than the Hating problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me show that your proposed $A$ is equivalent to the halting problem after all. Let $a_n$ be the $n$th element of $A$ by size; we have $a_n\ge BB(n)$, and so $A$ computes a function dominating $BB$. Since any function dominating $BB$ computes $0'$, we get $A\ge_T0'$. More generally, any infinite subset of $ran(BB)$ will compute $0'$.

In fact, there are currently no known examples of "natural" sets of intermediate degree, let alone r.e. ones. There are also very few candidate examples, and we have general results ruling out any "too-robust" such constructions. For example, see [Lachlan, *Uniform enumeration operations*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272164?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) or [Downey/Shore, *There is no degree invariant half-jump*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2162361). I've also written about this in more detail [at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2000834/28111).